# Can't access instance of a class in main method Java

Tags: java, instance

So I have a class used to describe a circle in the main method I'm supposed to see if two circle intersect. I need to make two instances of the class, and when I do this I can't access their values? The line with t doesn't work because it says it can't find Big or Lil?

```
if (r2 >= r1){
    MyCircle Big = new MyCircle(x2,y2,r2);
    MyCircle Lil = new MyCircle(x1,y1,r1);}
else { 
    MyCircle Big = new MyCircle(x1,y1,r1);
    MyCircle Lil = new MyCircle(x2,y2,r2);
}

t = Lil.getX()-Big.getX();
```

Comment: I recommend starting variable names with lower case letters. This is the accepted Java convention.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring Big and Lil inside two different scopes, so they can't be used outside.

Try this :

```
MyCircle Big = null;
MyCircle Lil = null;
if (r2>=r1){
    Big=new MyCircle(x2,y2,r2);
    Lil= new MyCircle(x1,y1,r1);
} else { 
    Big= new MyCircle(x1,y1,r1);
    Lil=new MyCircle(x2,y2,r2);}
}
t=Lil.getX()-Big.getX();
```

A "scope" in java starts with a "{" and ends with "}", everything declared inside these brakets, exists only inside these brackets.

Moreover :

1. Usually in java variables have lower case first letter, so "Big" should be "big" and "Lil" shoud be "lil". It's not a must, but is a well accepted convention. Class names should be upper case.
2. "t" is not declared in the snippet you posted, I hope it's defined before.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `Lil` and `Big` variables outside the `if` statement in order to access them outside the `if`/`else` blocks. When you define them within the `if` block (or `else` block) they only live within the scope of the `if`/`else` block.

```
MyCircle Big = null;
MyCircle Lil = null;
if (...) {
   ... // create instance of Big and Lil, but don't declare them here
} else (...) {
   ... // create instance of Big and Lil, but don't declare them here
}
... // access Big and Lil
```

Answer (score 0):

This is scoping issue. Every time you use curly braces you are defining a scope. Variables defined in that scope , are visible to that scope only. As a general rule: If want to access variables outside of the scope defined it out side accordingly.